# Cluster value changes in column in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have following data in csv:

```
+----+----------+-----+
|name| timestamp|value|
+----+----------+-----+
|   A|1604219844|    7|
|   A|1604219845|    1|
|   A|1604219846|    1|
|   A|1604219847|    1|
|   A|1604219848|    2|
|   A|1604219849|    7|
|   A|1604219850|    1|
|   A|1604219851|    1|
|   A|1604219852|    2|
|   A|1604219853|    7|
|   A|1604219854|    1|
|   A|1604219855|    1|
+----+----------+-----+
```

To track changes in sequential value, I have implemented the following code till now :

```
import findspark
findspark.init()

import pyspark # only run after findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

data = spark.read.option("header","true").csv("sample_data.csv")
data.show()

w = Window.orderBy("timestamp")
value_lag = lag('value').over(w)
timestamp_lag = lag('timestamp').over(w)

df_final = data.withColumn('prev_timestamp', timestamp_lag).withColumn('prev_value', value_lag)\
.withColumn("changed", (data.value != psf.lag('value').over(w)).cast('int'))\
.withColumn("diff",data.value - psf.lag('value').over(w))

df_final.show()
```

The output is as follows from above code:

```
+----+----------+-----+--------------+----------+-------+----+
|name| timestamp|value|prev_timestamp|prev_value|changed|diff|
+----+----------+-----+--------------+----------+-------+----+
|   A|1604219844|    7|          null|      null|   null|null|
|   A|1604219845|    1|    1604219844|         7|      1|-6.0|
|   A|1604219846|    1|    1604219845|         1|      0| 0.0|
|   A|1604219847|    1|    1604219846|         1|      0| 0.0|
|   A|1604219848|    2|    1604219847|         1|      1| 1.0|
|   A|1604219849|    7|    1604219848|         2|      1| 5.0|
|   A|1604219850|    1|    1604219849|         7|      1|-6.0|
|   A|1604219851|    1|    1604219850|         1|      0| 0.0|
|   A|1604219852|    2|    1604219851|         1|      1| 1.0|
|   A|1604219853|    7|    1604219852|         2|      1| 5.0|
|   A|1604219854|    1|    1604219853|         7|      1|-6.0|
|   A|1604219855|    1|    1604219854|         1|      0| 0.0|
+----+----------+-----+--------------+----------+-------+----+
```

I want to implement an additional column in above dataframe to cluster the changes `1 -> 2 -> 7 -> 1` occurring sequentially

```
+----+----------+-----+--------------+----------+-------+----+---------------+
|name| timestamp|value|prev_timestamp|prev_value|changed|diff|        keyword|
+----+----------+-----+--------------+----------+-------+----+---------------+
|   A|1604219844|    7|          null|      null|   null|null|           null|
|   A|1604219845|    1|    1604219844|         7|      1|  -6|Insert1-Update1|
|   A|1604219846|    1|    1604219845|         1|      0|   0|           null|
|   A|1604219847|    1|    1604219846|         1|      0|   0|           null|
|   A|1604219848|    2|    1604219847|         1|      1|   1|        Insert2|
|   A|1604219849|    7|    1604219848|         2|      1|   5|Insert2-Update1|
|   A|1604219850|    1|    1604219849|         7|      1|  -6|Insert2-Update2|
|   A|1604219851|    1|    1604219850|         1|      0|   0|           null|
|   A|1604219852|    2|    1604219851|         1|      1|   1|        Insert3|
|   A|1604219853|    7|    1604219852|         2|      1|   5|Insert3-Update1|
|   A|1604219854|    1|    1604219853|         7|      1|  -6|Insert3-Update2|
|   A|1604219855|    1|    1604219854|         1|      0|   0|           null|
+----+----------+-----+--------------+----------+-------+----+---------------+
```

The idea of this column will be that it can help in grouping the columns on basis of key `Insert2,Insert3` and then inside each of them `Insert2-Update1,Insert2-Update2` so that the final clustered result which need to be achieved is

```
+----+----------+-----+--------------+----------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
|name| timestamp|value|prev_timestamp|prev_value|changed_timestamp_1_to_2|changed_timestamp_2_to_7|changed_timestamp_7_to_1|
+----+----------+-----+--------------+----------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
|   A|1604219848|    2|    1604219847|         1|              1604219848|              1604219849|              1604219850|
|   A|1604219852|    2|    1604219851|         1|              1604219852|              1604219853|              1604219854|
+----+----------+-----+--------------+----------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Do you have other name values? Clustering example not well explained.

Comment: @thebluephantom.which portion is not clear?.the thing is I want to capture timestamp when value changes from 1 to 2,2 to 7 and then 7 to 1.I have seperate row for each vhange

Comment: so for example is the name always A?

Comment: yes..i have 30 columns but if it works for one column..it is easy to replicate for other columns.